# How do I set the accessibility label for a view in xcode4's interface builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, accessibility, functional-testing

I'm hoping to use [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF) to write functional tests for our iphone app.  It uses "accessibility labels" to identify the UI items it's testing.  How do I set the accessibility label for a view in xcode4's interface builder?

Comment: accessibilityLabel is read by VoiceOver. It is bad practice to use it as an identifier. You should use accessibilityIdentifer property which is not read by voiceover.

Comment: @Vlad No. It's *best* practise to use it in functional tests, because then you're also testing that your app is accessible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set the variable programmatically you can use its property like this:

```
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
someButton.titleLabel.text = @"Your Button's Text";
someButton.accessibilityLabel = @"SomeNSString";
```

---

In the InterfaceBuilder -- built into XCode 4 -- you just have to select the UI item you want to have an accessibility label. The "Identity Inspector", in the "Utility"-pane, offers a textfield where you can enter any label-text you want.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the Accessibility section in my IB - I've got Custom Class, User Defined Runtime Attributes, and Identity; but not Accessibility.

Comment: Clicking around, I can see Accessibility in most screens, but not in my MainWindow.xib - is that normal and if so, how do I set the accessibility labels there?

Comment: I think the UIWindow-class doesn't have the accessibility-properties. It really wouldn't make sense for a window to have accessibility-variables because usually they are only used by an iPhone, if the user has enabled "VoiceOver". On an iPhone -- where only one window is possible -- it is not necessary to identify a window.  
Programmatically it **is** possible.

Comment: OK - Makes sense.  I'm surprised I can't set it for its subviews, but I guess I can put them in separate nibs.