# iOS Webview app automation by using resource-id/ID using Appium

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

Can we do iOS **Webview** automation using resource-id attribute value?

And why can't we run the android, ios, and browser using one unique resource-id locator in appium?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Accessibility labels in the code and then find them by:

```
findElementByAccessibilityId
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, what exactly the difference b/w accessibilityid and normal id.

How to add accessibilityid, ios developers needs to add accessibilityid in html pagesource??

I tried 
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("id attribute value"); but showing no such element found exception.

Comment: There was a similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220739/how-do-i-set-the-accessibility-label-for-a-view-in-xcode4s-interface-builder

Comment: Thanks Slavo, I will ask dev team to add accessibility id for one attribute.
Have you tried this for your app Slavo.

Comment: Another Question,  After adding accessibility id in code appium inspector name attribute value will be mapped to assceessbilityid value???

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760384/appium-ios-automation-using-java-get-element-using-accessibility-id

Comment: Hi Slavo, I observed that accessibilityid can be add to native ios apps, but my app is webview which takes html attributes, could u please suggest how to add accessibility identifer for html elements??